# vb.net chart - use same chart for another dataset

Tags: vb.net, charts

Code throws an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the series seems to be non existent. When i try to debug single step, add the series again, throws an error because the series already exists...

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Chart1.Series.Add(row("Counter"))
    Chart1.Series(i).ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
    Chart1.Series(i).Label = 1
    Dim dp As Charting.DataPoint = New Charting.DataPoint()
    Dim sDay As String = row("Tag")
    If i = 0 Then
        sDayRowBefore = sDay
    Else
        If sDayRowBefore <> sDay Then
            iSeriesIndex = iSeriesIndex + 1
        End If
    End If
    dp.XValue = iSeriesIndex
    Chart1.Series(i).IsXValueIndexed = True
    dp.AxisLabel = row("Tag")
    dp.SetValueY(1)
    dp.Color = row("ItemFarbe")
    Chart1.Series(row("Counter")).Points.Add(dp)
    sDayRowBefore = sDay
    Chart1.DataManipulator.Filter(Charting.CompareMethod.EqualTo, 0, Chart1.Series(i))
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Error is only thrown when i use the same chart again for another dataset.
Before the chart is generated, i clear the series, points and chart area.

```
For Each var As Charting.Series In Chart1.Series
        var.Points.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: So the first time through `dt` works fine. Then you run the `For Each var` loop to `Clear` the `Points` from each currently existing `Series`. The second time through you have set `dt` to some other `DataTable` and `Chart1.Series(i).ChartType` gives your exception? Is that correct? What are the values of i and the `Count` property of the `SeriesCollection`? If you are recreating the `SeriesCollection` each time through, why aren't you calling `Series.Clear()` instead of clearing the points?

Comment: @topshot Sorry i wasnt more specific here.
`Chart1.Series(row("Counter")).Points.Add(dp)` is throwing the execption. Value of i is 0 -> working bc the series was added correctly, i can't add her again. Count of series collection is 1

Comment: And yes, i clear the series as well, just didnt post the code.

`Chart1.Series.Clear()
        Chart1.Legends.Clear()
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()`

Comment: Kinda found the error i hope, but i need someone to confirm this.
I tried to reference the series by name with Chart1.Series(row("Counter")) which returns an int from the dt. Instead of the series name it was referenced by this index, in my case the "Counter" row returned 6 and the index 6 wasnt there. 
Which brings me to the question, how to reference a series by name?

Comment: Chart1.Series("6")

Comment: Thanks but how to do it with a variable that returns an integer?

Comment: `Chart1.Series.Add(row("Counter").ToString)` If you don't already, always use `Option Strict On`, too.

Comment: @topshot can you post it as an answer so i can accept it as yours? Thanks again